# x509_sign routine fails with ASN1 encoding routine error

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am writing a simple sSL Server code in C using OpenSSL library.
I use an RSA Private Key PEM file along with it's certificate PEM file as input parameters. Here is how I do this:

```
EVP_PKEY *pkey= NULL;
pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();

if(EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(pkey, pkey_RSA) == 0){
    printf("RSA_set1_key  failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
    const char* error_string = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
    printf("RSA_set1_key returns %s\n", error_string);
}
printf("An RSA key Object created with modulus and exponent params\n");
EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, pkey_RSA);

X509 *x509 = X509_new();
X509_set_version(x509, 2);
ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(x509), 0);
X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509), 0);
X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509), (long)60*60*24*365);
X509_set_pubkey(x509, pkey);

X509_NAME *name = X509_get_subject_name(x509);
X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "C",  MBSTRING_ASC,
        (unsigned char *)"IN", -1, -1, 0);
X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "O",  MBSTRING_ASC,
        (unsigned char *)"Company", -1, -1, 0);
X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC,
        (unsigned char *)"localhost", -1, -1, 0);
X509_set_issuer_name(x509, name);

if(X509_sign(x509, pkey, EVP_sha256()) == 0){
    printf("X509_sign  failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
    const char* error_string = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
    printf("X509_sign returns %s\n", error_string);
} 

SSL_CTX_use_certificate(ctx, x509);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey(ctx, pkey);

SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, 0);
```

This code seems to produce error at X509_sign as follows:

```
X509_sign  failed, error 0x6089095
X509_sign returns error:0D0DC006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_sign_ctx:EVP lib
```

I am unable to comprehend the error and proceed. Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of OpenSSL? And have you tried doing the same things manually with `openssl` commands on the same crypto material you are using?

Comment: openssl 1.1.0g.

Comment: Yes. I want to understand where and what is thecause of this error.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is the error? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Openssl errors are notoriously bad to debug. Like I already asked: did you try to do the same things using `openssl` in CLI to see if it works?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks will try and let you know. At the moment my system has no CLI. Only the libssl and libcrypto.